# Task scheduler for Windows capable to run tasks every X minutes

Tags: windows-10, scheduling

I am having big difficulties with the Windows Task Scheduler in Windows 10 - getting some weird "An error has occurred for task" errors.

So I need a program that can schedule tasks but one that is capable to run a task every 5 minutes. Some task schedule programs can only run a task daily, and then they are useless for me.